# Getting SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Tags: javascript, laravel-blade

This is the error I'm getting:

> SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
>
> note: [ opened at line 959, column 12

This is refered output:

```
var specifications = [
   [ "<option value="'1'">"'CPU'"</option>" ],
   [ "<option value="'2'">"'ram'"</option>" ],
   [ "<option value="'3'">"'LCD'"</option>" ],
   [ "<option value="'4'">"'Mouse'"</option>" ],
   [ "<option value="'5'">"'Graphic'"</option>" ],
   [ "<option value="'6'">"'Keyboard'"</option>" ],
];
```

This is my code:

```
var specifications = [
    @foreach($specifications as $specification)
        [ "<option value="'{{ $specification->id }}'">"'{{ $specification->title }}'"</option>" ],
    @endforeach
];
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Your code is not JavaScript `@foreach` and `@endforeach` are syntax errors in JavaScript. Please add the correct tag for the language you are using.

Comment: @Paulpro I'm aware of that but somehow I'm in need to use this php data inside my javascript, if there is better way to loop my data i'm open to hear it.

Comment: Is this razor code? PHP? I'm not sure what language you're referring to.

Comment: @IsaacAbramowitz that's laravel php.

Comment: Ah, you mean Blade. I'll add the correct tag.

Comment: Just to clarify, this question has little to do with PHP. You are using a templating language called Blade (A PHP framework called Laravel's default templaing language) to output JavaScript. You had a syntax error in your Blade template @Minderov's answer has the fix for it.

Comment: `@{directive}` directives, in `blade` templating, are valid in JS so long as they're being called in a `<script>...</script>` tag *within* a `.blade.php` file. So yeah, while it looks messy and like it should be a syntax error, it's essentially shorthand for `<?php echo ...; ?>` and similar.

Comment: @TimLewis `@foreach` in that context is definitely a syntax error in JavaScript. Blade templates can ***output*** valid JavaScript, just like any templating language; but that doesn't mean they ***are*** valid JavaScript.

Comment: Yes I understand, and I think we're saying the same thing, just differently.

Comment: @TimLewis Yeah, I think so. I originally said they are syntax errors because the OP had only tagged this JavaScript and had not mentioned Laravel until later in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have unescaped quote marks in your strings.

Consider one of the inputs:
`"<option value="'1'">"'CPU'"</option>"`. It starts with `"` and ends with `"`. But it also has bunch of `"`s in the middle, which confuses the parser. So any `"`s you have in-between you have to escape by changing them to `\"`:

```
var specifications = [
    @foreach($specifications as $specification)
        [ "<option value=\"'{{ $specification->id }}'\">\"'{{ $specification->title }}'\"</option>" ],
    @endforeach
];
```

Edit: actually, it looks like you don't need so many quote marks.
Consider changing

`"<option value="'1'">"'CPU'"</option>"`

to

`"<option value='1'>CPU</option>"`

In that case you don't need to escape anything and your code will look a little cleaner:

```
var specifications = [
    @foreach($specifications as $specification)
        [ "<option value='{{ $specification->id }}'>{{ $specification->title }}</option>" ],
    @endforeach
];
```

Comment: that was it <3 thank you. but it's better this way `[ "<option value=\"'{{ $specification->id }}'\">{{ $specification->title }}</option>" ],`